# iOS libsystem_c.dylib strdup memory leak NSZombie not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, instruments, nszombie

Please help me track down an iOS memory leak. Thanks!

I'm using xCode 4.0.1 and I tried to activate NSZombie to track a memory leak, but it doesn't seems to work as before, with xCode 3.x

I can't find out where the memory leak is coming from, as Instruments points this out:

Leaked Object              -> **GeneralBlock-32**
Address                    -> **0x4c8600**
Size                       -> **32 Bytes**
Responsible Library        -> **libsystem_c.dylib**
Responsible Frame/Caller   -> **strup**

At this point I don't know If I'm using **Instruments** with NSZombie the right way with xCode 4, as it doesn't show the NSZombie option when I click "i" for more information, under the left option **Leaks**.

**OBSERVATION**: My iPhone application plays a live stream mms/wma and also wma áudio files with a finite amount of time. The leak happens **only** with a finite wma file, but **runs perfectly** when I'm playing from a streamed source, with no ending time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, that is a `malloc` block, not an object.  Zombies won't work (and would never have worked in prior versions either).

How many times does that leak happen?  Once? Don't worry about it.  Once per stream?  file a bug -- that isn't in your code from what you have posted so far (unless your code is calling `strdup`, which is certainly possible but atypical in most iOS apps that aren't making heavy use of third party libraries... are you?)

In any case, unless it is leaking 100s and 100s of 32 byte allocations across the runtime of your app, don't worry about it (but please do file a bug).

As Valkio said, you can grab the stack trace of the allocation from gdb (or from Instruments) directly.

Comment: Thanks for your considerations, bbum. I'll file a bug report. And yes, I'm making heavy use of third party libraries: LibMMS (for parsing the audio stream) and FFMPeg (for decoding/playing) the WMA file. In this case, what should I look for? Because when I open a second stream, at end of the first stream, my app crashes when I manually stop the audio. I don't call strdup myself, unless the libraries I'm using is doing that. UPDATE: yes, LibMMS is calling strup when It makes the mms connection.

Comment: A bug report probably won't do you much good if it is in a third party library. Sounds like a leak in that library.  The crash is probably orthogonal (though it could boil down to a memory management issue in the library) and worthy of a different question.

Answer (score 5):

You can see where it was allocated if you do this:

1. Go to Product -> Edit Scheme -> Run
   (Debug) -> Arguments.
2. Add this to environment variables: **MallocStackLoggingNoCompact**
3. Set it to **YES**
4. Run, and let it crash.
5. type in console (gdb) **info malloc 0x4c8600** or whatever the address is.

Comment: You can do this in Instruments, too.  No need for gdb;  click through the allocation's address in Instruments and it'll show the allocation stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, vakio. I did as you instructed me and in (gdb) when I typed info malloc 0x464890, it gave me this output: MyAppName (330) >   What does this 330 means?

Comment: Hm that's not right. You should get a malloc stack. Maybe instruments will work better in this case...

Comment: please, if you would, take a look at my response to bbum. thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem except its leaking in 48 byte increments instead of 32 bytes. I'm using iOS 5.1 and the leak seems to be related to a UIScrollView scrolling with images. The leak doesn't seem big enough to worry too much, but still I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did anybody solve this problem with little malloc leaks? I'm having it now, and when these errors pile up they crash my app...