# Memory Leak in libsystem_c.dylib strdup

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

Getting memory leak in instruments when i m trying to test app. In app when i test youtube video in UIWebView it shows malloc Memory Leak in libsystem_c.dylib responsible framse showing is strdup.

```
-(void)LaunchVideo:(id)sender
{

    self.videoURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/0Xa4bHcJu8";

    //VideoViewController *videoViewController = [[[VideoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] retain];

VideoViewController *videoViewController = [[VideoViewController alloc] init];


    videoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    videoViewController.videoURL = self.videoURL;

    [self presentModalViewController:videoViewController animated:YES];

    [videoViewController release];
}
```

EDIT:

Below is the stack trace:

```
0 libsystem_c.dylib malloc
1 libsystem_c.dylib strdup
2 libnotify.dylib token_table_add
3 libnotify.dylib notify_register_check
4 AVFoundation -[AVPlayer(AVPlayerMultitaskSupport) _iapdExtendedModeIsActive]
6 AVFoundation -[AVQueuePlayer init]
7 MediaPlayer -[MPQueuePlayer init]
23 MediaPlayer -[UIMoviePlayerController setAutoRotationMask:]
24 QuickTime Plugin 0x89473ce
27 QuickTime Plugin 0x894f3bc
28 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_call_block_and_release
29 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
30 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
32 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
33 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
34 UIKit UIApplicationMain
```

Anyone can tell why the leak is and what is the cause.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tried googling for similar problems? I just did, and I found this:

[iOS libsystem_c.dylib strdup memory leak NSZombie not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899419/ios-libsystem-c-dylib-strdup-memory-leak-nszombie-not-working)

To summarise, it may be a leak in a library you're not responsible for. If that's the case, and it's a tiny one-off leak, don't sweat it.

Comment: as soon as it starts playing youtube video it shows me this leak in instruments. It is malloc 48bytes